# Clarifying AVP versus DSP in the FAQ

Tags: discussion, scope, faq-proposed

It came up in conversation that the distinction is not entirely clear between DSP.Stackexchange, the site for technical DSP discussion, and AVP.Stackexchange, this site, which is focused on recording and editing but where signals are most definitely being processed.

To clarify, I would like to amend [our FAQ](https://video.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)'s bullet point from:

- Signal Processing

to:

- Signal processing in a production context (for highly technical questions about digital signal processing, please visit [Stack Exchange's DSP site](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/))

Comments and discussion are welcome, as are suggestions for better wording. I would like to reach a consensus before changing it.

### Update:

Since it's been a while and there doesn't seem to be any dissent I've made the change to the FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

Just some background: signal processing was not in the original scope and was added before DSP.SE existed.  The original discussion is [here](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/q/91/64).

To be honest, I think "Signal processing in a production context" questions would fit in here under other existing tags like [effects](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effects) or [filter](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filter), but for the sake of clarity I'd support your proposed changes.